# Excel Date to Text Day and Month always mix up

Tags: excel, vba

I'm exploring the use of `Userform` on my Excel VBA project and I want to create a form which will convert date from a DTPicker into text on a text box.

The reason for doing this is because I need the date to be in a specific format of `yyyy/mm/dd` to search an SQL query and the DTPicker value always default to `dd-m-yyyy`. Giving me no results in the query.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub convertDate()

TextBox1 = DateFrmMac.Value
Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Me.TextBox1.Text, "yyyy/mm/dd")
TextBox2 = DateToMac.Value
Me.TextBox2.Text = Format(Me.TextBox2.Text, "yyyy/mm/dd")

End Sub
```

During testing if the date is for example `29/1/2020`, the conversion can work as intended. But if the day is below 12, like `8/11/2019`, the day and month will mix up its values and give me the wrong date.

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Maybe look into the .local property, that's usually the issue messing my dates up. I don't use the date picker tool though.

Comment: .local property as in my PC settings or Excel settings?

Comment: `TextBox2` variable, which takes the date from DTPicker, is a string variable? If not, what is it? It is recommended to avoid creating variables having control names. This can be confusing.

Comment: @hjh93: If you simple use `Debug.Print TextBox1` what does it return? And  what  `Debug.Print  Cstr(TextBox1)` does return? I am asking that to supply a solution if what  I imagine it really happens... I do not use a DTPicker.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Sorry for late reply. Tested the debug print for both versions.  Both returns `2019/02/12` when i pick the date `2019/12/02`.

Comment: @hjh93: I would also like to know what `Debug.Print CStr(DateFrmMac.Value)` returns. I made a piece of code which will allow you to solve the problem independent of localization, I think. It is not place here to post it in a way to understand it. In fact, I will post it like an answer and it will also contain the above line. If it does not solve your problem, please tell me what the `Debug.Print` line returns...

Comment: `Debug.Print CStr(DateFrmMac.Value)` gives me `3/1/2020` when I pick `3/1/2020`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Private Sub convertDate()
     Dim d As Date, strT1 As String, strT2 As String
     strT1 = CStr(DateFrmMac.Value): Debug.Print strT1 'for 2019/12/5 use
     d = DateSerial(Split(strT1, "/")(0), Split(strT1, "/")(1), Split(strT1, "/")
(2))
     'for strT1 = "5/12/2019" use:
     d = DateSerial(Split(strT1, "/")(2), Split(strT1, "/")(1), Split(strT1, "/")
(0))
     Me.TextBox1.text = Format(d, "yyyy/mm/dd")
     strT2 = CStr(DateToMac.Value)
     d = DateSerial(Split(strT2, "/")(0), Split(strT2, "/")(1), Split(strT2, "/")(2))
     Me.TextBox2.text = Format(d, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    End Sub
```

Comment: OK. I tried out the code but the date in the textbox is much different than in DTPicker.  When I choose `2020/01/29` in picker, textbox shows `2034/07/13`. `2019/12/05` gives me `2011/06/11`.

Comment: the `Debug.Print strT1` gives me the correct date though as `5/12/2019`.

Comment: So I played around with the code on DateSerial. Changed the split arrangement to `Split(strT1, "/")(2), Split(strT1, "/")(1), Split(strT1, "/")(0)`. And the date comes out fine now. Will need to test it out on SQL query but for now can be considered a success.

Comment: @hjh93: So looked my code initially, seeing your initial question. But when I asked  about `Debug.Print Cstr(TextBox1)` you told me that it returns `2019/12/02`. Maybe I was not clear enough... I wanted to refer to the textbox  value **before** formatting... You had in your code `TextBox1 = DateFrmMac.Value`  followed by `Me.TextBox1.Text = Format(Me.TextBox1.Text, "yyyy/mm/dd")`. I've just thought you will understand what I mean. But, I would like to believe that it is better for you to discover by yourself the logic behind the solution. In this way you will remember it forever :-)...

Comment: @hjh93: I adapted the code to explain when the proposed solution is good to be used according to the date picker format...